# Connect with WinSCP through a wallix Bastion doesn't work but PuTTY is fine

Tags: putty, ssh-tunnel, winscp

When connecting to PuTTY to my Wallix Bastion SomeBastionAdress.fr it works fine (sensitive data has been anonymized):

```
login as: MyLogin
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
| WARNING: Access to this system is restricted to duly authorized users only. A
> ny attempt to access this system without authorization or fraudulently remain
> ing within such system will be prosecuted in accordance with the law. Any aut
> horized user is hereby informed and acknowledges that his/her actions may be
> recorded, retained and audited.
|
| MyLogin's password:
End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
| ID | Cible (page 1/1)                        | Autorisation
|----|-----------------------------------------|--------------------
|  0 | SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH       | ExpeOL-usersLocaux
|  1 | SomeAdress2@SomeLinuxServer2:SSH | ExpeOL-usersLocaux
|  2 | SomeAdress3@SomeLinuxServer3:SSH | ExpeOL-usersLocaux
|  3 | SomeAdress4@SomeLinuxServer4:SSH                     | ExpeOL-usersLocaux
Tapez h pour l'aide, ctrl-D pour quitter
 > 0
Cible sélectionnée: SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH
Account successfully checked out
Adresse cible (dans 10.192.0.0/14): LinuxMachineName
Login cible: julien
julien's password:

Vous êtes informé(e) et reconnaissez que vos actions sont susceptibles d’être en                                                                             registrées, conservées et auditées conformément à la politique de sécurité de vo                                                                             tre organisation.
Veuillez vous rapprocher de votre administrateur WALLIX Bastion pour plus d’info                                                                             rmations.

Linux LinuxMachineName 4.9.0-19-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.320-2 (2022-06-30) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Fri Dec 22 17:26:28 2023 from 10.192.67.26
julien@LinuxMachineName:~$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
10.192.67.26 34116 10.192.118.77 22
```

I now want to connect with WinSCP so I can secure copy files from local to my server.

I used:

```
File protocol: SCP
Host name: SomeBastionAdress.fr
User name: SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH:MyLogin
```

[image]

I also tried several other User names without success:

```
User name: julien@LinuxMachineName:SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH:MyLogin
User name: julien:SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH:MyLogin
User name: julien@SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH:MyLogin
etc. (I tried many combinations)
```

But that does not work, WinSCP is stuck here:

```
Authenticating...
Using username "SomeAdress@SomeLinuxServer:SSH:MyLogin"
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated
Starting the session...
```

[image]

I also tried SFTP and I get the following message error:

```
Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 255 Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
```

[image]

When changing the SFTP protocol to `/bin/sftp-server` instead of `Default`, I get the following message error. This is also the same message error when using `sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server`

```
Received too large (109710925 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 1024000 B. The error is typically caused by message printed from startup script (like .profile). The message may start with "Adre". Cannot Initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
```

[image]

I also changed the Shell when in SFTP without success.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, you can connect and even authenticate with WinSCP. The problem is initiating the SCP/SFTP session. So your comparison to PuTTY is irrelevant. Can you use any other SFTP client against your server?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the shell settings for SCP or SFTP within _Advanced_ → _Environment_ → **when _File Protocol_ is SCP:** _SCP/shell_ → _Protocol Options_: _Shell_ || **when _File Protocol_ is SFTP:** _SFTP_ → _Protocol Options_: _SFTP server_

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thanks for your comment, I have tried FileZilla and the result is the same: `Status: Connected to SomeBastionAddress.fr
Error: Could not connect to server`

Comment: @JW0914, thanks for your comment! yes I have tried all possible combinations. When using SCP I always get `Error skipping startup message. Your shell is probably incompatible with the application (BASH is recommended).` no matter if I try `/bin/sh` or `default` or one of the 5 allowed possibilities. For SFTP, I also tried all combinations and got a different error message: `Received too large (Nb. of B) SFTP packet. Max supported size is Other Nb. of Bytes`

Comment: So is the server even supposed to support SFTP? + The SFTP error message is important, it should be prominently in the question (in complete exact form, including the exact numbers), not buried here in the comments.

Comment: Note for those who don't know Wallix: it's a ssh (and other protocols) proxy intended to log all activity (anything displayed). But it provides no shell. So I would expect SCP to fail and SFTP to work, but only if the login profile enables the use of SFTP.

Comment: In general, please do not post errors (only) as an image. Post them as a text (too). + Did you read https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thank you for your comment :) I think SFTP is supported by the server as `sftp`, `curl` and `scp` commands work when I am logged in via PuTTY. I edited my question to add the messages errors when trying to connect via SFTP thanks to your suggestion

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I just read winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet as you suggested, and I `moved the commands from .bashrc script to .bash_profile` as they wrote and still got the same number of bytes displayed in the message error. There are other `.files` such as `.Xauthority` or `.profile`. Should I care about them?

Comment: The fact that SFTP client work on a machine [the server] does not mean the machine works as an SFTP server. + The SFTP error message explains that there's conflicting message starting with *"Adre"*. It might be the *"Adresse cible (dans 10.192.0.0/14): LinuxMachineName"* in your SSH session transcript. You have to get rid of that.